# MISRA C mapping to Klocwork violations

Tags: c, misra

Is there a mapping between MISRA rules for example:

- A function shall not be declared implicitly (MISRA C R.17.3), such as use "int f(int x);" and not " f(x);".
- All exit paths from a function with non-void return type shall have an explicit return statement with an expression (MISRA C R.17.4).

into a Klocwork checker?

for example I was able to find:
requierment: The operand of the sizeof operator shall not contain any expression that has potential side effects (MISRA C R.13.6).

klocwork: MISRA.SIZEOF.SIDE_EFFECT  Operand of sizeof has side effects  5-3-4   Pre-2020.1

how do you handle these for MISRA C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, tool vendors have a many-to-many mapping between their own in-house mappings, and third-party rule-sets such as MISRA C or CERT C.

Klocwork themselves provide the mappings in their product documentation:.

https://help.klocwork.com/current/en-us/concepts/misrac2012_amd1nolinks.htm

*Note: Answer expanded by Andrew, to address review comment (which can, hopefully, now be deleted)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).